# Tablesoreter Filter Widget / Scroller Widget/ columns width

Tags: tablesorter

if I use Tablesorter with
scroller 
filter
bootstrap theme
the column widths are not the same like the widths of thead
any known issues?

```
[visible here in this jsfiddle][1]
```

sincerely
    [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/enoopxmf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `table-layout: fixed;` definition and it should work fine ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/enoopxmf/2/)).